# ListView scrolling smoothness

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have a fully functional `listview` (in a `ListFragment`) with a custom `ArrayAdapter`.
The layout of the adapter consists of an `imageview`, a `button`, a `gridview` and a couple of     `textviews`.
The problem is the listview is very jittery while scrolling. I have implemented the `ViewHolder` pattern and it improved the performance just a little.
The `GridView` consists of contact images which i am retrieving in a `AsyncTask` and also using application cache to display the bitmaps.
What else can i do to make this `listview` scroll smooth?
I have used view recycling as shown below in my `getView` method of the adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View myView;
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                                  Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_list_activity, parent, false);
    }
    else {
        myView = convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you correctly recycled the `View`s used in each item of your `ListView`?

Comment: You have a `GridView` in every single row of your `ListView`? If that's the case, then my next guess is that the touch action of scrolling is being delegated to the `GridView` child which makes it jittery. Try turning touch actions off for all of your `GridView`s and see if that helps, then try removing all of the `GridView`s and see if the problem is gone. Without much code, all we can do is take guesses ;)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6293919/1626878) question might have explanation for jittery behaviour of your list view.

If you are looking to improve scrolling speed, try this,

```
getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't help as i have already taken care of all that. I don't have any heavy operations running on my Adapter. Also `setFastScrollEnabled` is not the solution as the listView will still be jittery while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

1.Flatten your ViewItem hierarchy & use merge tag

2.Implement ViewHolder pattern, or use inject feature of androidannotation

3.Do the heavyload in another thread.

Answer (score -1):

It will give you the scroll from top of your layout and also it'll give you smooth scrolling experience.

```
mainScrollView=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
mainScrollView.fullScroll(mainScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```

Comment: yes but my issue is pertaining to a `listview`, how is a `scrollview` going to make any difference?